# HbaseSink Flume Exception

Tags: java, hbase, flume

Following is my flume Sink code to split event and store in Hbase,It gives me error when it takes null event

```
    public class MyHbaseEventSerializer implements HbaseEventSerializer {
     @Override
      public void configure(Context context){}
    @Override
      public void initialize(Event event, byte[] columnFamily) {

          this.payload = event.getBody();
          this.cf = columnFamily;
          this.e = event;    

     }
     @Override
   public List<Row> getActions() throws FlumeException {
     List<Row> actions = Lists.newArrayList();
    try{
       // here splitting event and store in Hbase.
    }catch(Exception e){
      throw new FlumeException("Could not get row key!", e);
      }
    return actions
  }
   @Override
  public List<Increment> getIncrements() {
    List<Increment> incs = new LinkedList<Increment>();
  }
  @Override
  public void close() {}

    }
```

It Continuous infinite with this error
ERROR : [SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] (org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run:160)  - Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: begin() called when transaction is OPEN!
at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicTransactionSemantics.begin(BasicTransactionSemantics.java:131)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.HBaseSink.process(HBaseSink.java:234)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
    at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Has any one solution to resolve this

Thanks in advance..